# How to find lines of objective c method implementations using libclang

Tags: objective-c, parsing, methods, libclang

I want to get the line numbers where the implementation of objective c method start.

```
1 #include "foobar.h"
2 -(void)Foo{
3 ...
4 }
5
6 +(NSInteger *)bar{
7 ...
8 }
```

**The output should be: 2,6**

How can i achieve it with **libclang**.

*I do not want to use a regex for that, because it will be sufficient.*

Comment: Have you looked up `libclang`? Do you know its functionality? What have you tried? SO exists as a way to get specific questions answered — Google exists for everything else. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solution:

CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(cursor);
CXSourceLocation startLocation = clang_getRangeStart(range);
CXSourceLocation endLocation = clang_getRangeEnd(range);

CXFile file;
unsigned int line, column, offset;
clang_getInstantiationLocation(startLocation, &file, &line, &column, &offset);

enum CXCursorKind curKind  = clang_getCursorKind(cursor);
CXString curKindName  = clang_getCursorKindSpelling(curKind);
const char *funcDecl="ObjCInstanceMethodDecl";

if(strcmp(clang_getCString(curKindName),funcDecl)==0){
  printf("%u",line);
}
```